# How can I remove the unwanted space before the header in Wordpress Twenty Twenty Three?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to remove space before header in word press twenty twenty three

Hi,

I've gone through every resource I can and I've spent over 6 hours just trying to configure this header spacing right, could anyone please help?

What custom CSS can I use to overcomb this, and which template part would I put it in?

Issue photo:
[image: Issue photo]
Its in the #body?
[image: Its in the #body?]

Thank you in advance ~
-Nick

I tried the margin css methods and nothing worked.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question hasn't been answered yet, I'd like to provide a step-by-step solution to help you remove the space before the header. Follow these instructions:

1. Click on the "Styles" navigation.
2. Go to the "Layouts" section.
3. Find the padding property and set it to 0.

I've also created an illustration to visually guide you through these steps:

[image: Remove Unwated Space Before heading: Step 1 and 2]

[image: Remove Unwated Space Before heading: Step 3]

Comment: This isn't the problem reported, although you might ADDITIONALLY have this set to non-zero

Comment: This removes the space before the header as the OP asked. Of course the value can be set to non-zero, but the OP wanted to remove the space, not overlap or increase the space. Can you provide more insight as to how the solution proposed doesn't solve the problem and how being able set the value to non-zero makes a difference with regards to the solution proposed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when I started by choosing the "Block Out" style (the red option) it solved part of your problem. It's not just colors and fonts, it also affects the layout and removes that space above the header (the dark green in your example).

[Here's where to find the style I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrZeZ.png)

Just note that if you do that, it *will* overwrite your other styles. You kinda have to start from scratch, I think.

Comment: This isn't sufficient. After starting with a different style, then switching to Block Out, the excess margin is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across your post as I was also searching for an answer. But I was able to figure it out.
Just go to the site editor and under Styles -> Padding, enter 0px for `top`.

Attached photo:
[Removing space above header in WP 2023 Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjxB9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I add the following CSS code as shown below to the theme and it works:

`main#wp--skip-link--target { margin-top: 0 !important; margin-bottom: 0 !important; padding-top: 0 !important; padding-bottom: 0 !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Note that this theme originally worked correctly (see this post for evidence: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/theme-twenty-twenty-three/) until it seems someone who didn't know how to use Block Themes / didn't read the docs (https://developer.wordpress.org/news/2023/03/22/everything-you-need-to-know-about-spacing-in-block-themes/ ) edited the raw .php files and hardcoded the unwanted space (how themes used to be done in Wordpress 4/5).

There's also some bugs in Wordpress6 that affect this theme (see below) but to fix the main problem, you need to edit the theme and remove the hardcoded items. Files are:

- templates/single.html
- templates/archive.html
- templates/page.html <-- this is the one that affects most of us
- templates/home.html <-- this is the one that affects most of us
- parts/header.html <-- you need to ALSO do this one, they hardcoded a pointless 40 spacer into the header for no apparent reason.

Additional bug in Wordpress 6:

- If your theme (2023 in this case) has a "margin-top" set to 0 ... it *will not be zero* because Wordpress6 is ... hmm. You literally have to go into the main layout for the theme, set margin-top to "1" then back to "0" -- and you'll see the theme update in preview with *less margin than it had when you arrived on the screen*. This applies in a few places: you have to go through every block and change the values to 'something' then back to the '0' they claimed to have